# Play 2.5 using dependency injection in template

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.5, twirl

I upgraded to Play 2.5 and moving everything to dependency injection. The class `UiCommonService` is now service, that is injectable, it used to be static.

This is how the the controller looks like.

```
public Result index() {
    if (CurrentUserService.isAuthenticated()) {
        return ok(mainPage.render(CurrentUserService.getUserStateVariables(),
                CurrentUserService.getCurrentUser(),
                configService.getGoogleAnalyticsKey()));
    } else {
        return redirect("/login");
    }
}
```

This is how my scala template looks like, it is using the `@import` command to use the static method from class.

```
@(variables: String, authorisedUser: models.security.UserSession, gaKey: String)

@import services.ui.UiCommonService

@layout.masterPage(UiCommonService.getSimpleHeaderAttributes(), styles){
    // my custom layout code
}
```

I read that to use dependency injection I have to include it with @this attribute.

```
@this(uiCommonService: services.ui.UiCommonService)

@(variables: String, authorisedUser: models.security.UserSession, gaKey: String)

@layout.masterPage(uiCommonService.getSimpleHeaderAttributes(), styles){
    // my custom layout code
}
```

But now I getting error at my controller `controller.index()` method.

```
mainPage.scala.html:1: too many arguments for method apply: ()play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in class mainPage
```

Comment: Are you using Java or Scala? There seems to be a mix in your question.

Comment: Java as backend, but Play uses Twirl on frontend, which is Scala based template language.